# Does google drive protect against zip bombs?

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, xlsx

Considering that xlsx can be used as a zip bomb and drive api can convert it into a sheet, I am wondering if there are any checks to prevent a conversion in case of a zip bomb? I have tried checking the docs but did not find any relevant information there. I did not find any such info on Stack overflow either.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, Google Drive does not protect you from zip bombs.

Today, I verified that Google Drive will upload and store a **zip bomb**. Google Drive scans files under 100 MB for known viruses. I am not sure how Google classifies a zip bomb for storage and if the scanner will detect the zip bomb in the future. In the short term, the zip bomb is not flagged in Google Drive.

Google Chrome and Firefox detect zip bombs and prevent their download. Microsoft Edge permitted the download of the zip bomb.

Using the Google Drive integration with Windows Explorer (Windows 10 Professional) permitted the download of a zip bomb stored in Google Drive.

Most antivirus software will quarantine zip bombs during file scans and during downloads.

Therefore, you will need to implement additional strategies to protect systems from zip bombs.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response. But is this also the case for xlsx files? For all other zip files, this may be true because in all those cases you can't actually unzip the file in drive. However, google actually unpacks xlsx to sheet as part of their API functionality. Did they include any security measures for that?

Comment: @javaassassin - I am not aware of public documents specifying protection from XLSX zip bombs. Therefore, at this time, my answer is that you are not protected. Implement strategies to prevent the upload in the first place via Antivirus software. I have verified that one case uploads, therefore to be protected all uploads must be prevented.